# Trailing edge flap disadvantages

Tags: aerodynamics, flaps, fluid-mechanics

What does ‘high local surface curvature’ mean with respect to trailing edge flaps?

I’ve been reading up on them, and that came up as one of their disadvantages?

Comment: Can you post the complete sentence that doesn't sound good to you?

Answer (score 1):

"High local surface curvature" means greater tendency for airflow separation, which increases drag.

When landing, this can be beneficial to a very "slick" aircraft because it steepens the glide angle and helps control airspeed.

The term "streamlining" refers to smooth gentle curves on aerodynamic surfaces, tending to keep airflow attached.  "Laminar" is best for lowest drag.

Comment: Hi Robert, I’m still a little confused about what high local surface curvature still means? Does it have any meaning relating to the geometry? Could I say it means too much curvature please?

Comment: @MikeKnows Yes, or a sharp bend or angle.  Moving air becomes turbulent if it cannot follow a curve.  A little like a car going to fast for a turn.  The gentler the turn, the smoother the flow.